# Kendo UI Grid Manual Save

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid and a datasource for the grid that is binding a bunch of rows to it. Each row that is being pullef rom the datasource is a model that has a navigation property. However, when I create a new row and save it using the default kendo "save" function for the grid, the navigation properties are not initialized. I need to be able to create a new table for the navigation property in my grid. I have the following setup.

```
        $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: viewmodel.model.AChecklistCompleteSource,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "createdBy",
                title: "Created By",
                width: 200
            },
            {
                field: "dateCreated",
                title: "Date Created"
            },
            {
                field: "dateModified",
                title: "Date Modified"
            },
            { command: { text: "View Checklist", click: viewmodel.model.showDetails }, title: " ", width: "180px" }
            ],
            toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Create Checklist" }, { name: "save", text: "Save Checklist" }, "cancel"],
            editable: "inline",
            saveChanges: function (e) {
                 //How do I manually save here so that my navigation property is not null for this row's model? 
                if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to save all changes?")) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            },
            height: 500
        });
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my entity framework code first model with two navigation properties that are null when the kendo grid creates a new row:

```
    public partial class AChecklistComplete
{
    [Key]
    public int AChecklistCompleteID { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ChecklistTop AChecklistTop { get; set; }
    public virtual Aircraft Aircraft { get; set; }
}
```

My AChecklistCompleteSource  just has a list of these models. When kendo creates a new row, it lets me create and save a row with this model, but Aircraft and AChecklistTop are null, and I would like to manually initialize them(or automatic if possible) so that I can bind to them on my form at some point(i.e somefield=AChecklistComplete.Aircraft.SomeField)

Comment: You should validate your model, when validation fails, then saving doesn't happen either. So, you should attach a kendoValidator

Comment: That is super helpful, thanks. But how would I initialize my navigation property in my model when I create a new kendo row?

Comment: could you give me a hint on what it should do?

Comment: @JohnEdwards What navigation property? What does it point to? It would help if you showed us what a `AChecklistComplete` data element looked like. The only info you've given is it has a `createdBy`, `dateCreated`, and `dateModified` property.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it was needed since I just need to learn how to intercept the kendo row creation process and set the object myself. I will edit the post.

Comment: So, it would be the edit event you are looking for? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit , i only asked for the navigation property to have no misunderstandings :D

Comment: Yea! I think that is it. I guess I was looking for something in the saveChanges event instead of edit. Thanks a ton!